# Calculate total difference of values between two timestamps

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f43fca2b07271746834c558ec7113f60)**

```
CREATE TABLE logistics (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    time_stamp DATE,
    product VARCHAR(255),
    quantity INT
);

INSERT INTO logistics
(time_stamp, product, quantity)
VALUES 
('2020-01-14', 'Product_A', '100'),
('2020-01-14', 'Product_B', '300'),

('2020-01-15', 'Product_B', '400'),
('2020-01-15', 'Product_C', '350'),

('2020-01-16', 'Product_B', '530'),
('2020-01-16', 'Product_C', '350'),
('2020-01-16', 'Product_D', '670'),

('2020-01-17', 'Product_C', '500'),
('2020-01-17', 'Product_D', '980'),
('2020-01-17', 'Product_E', '700'),
('2020-01-17', 'Product_F', '450');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
time_stamp  |   difference   |           info
------------|----------------|--------------------------------------
2020-01-14  |       400      |       =(100+300)
2020-01-15  |       350      |       =(400+350)-(300+100)
2020-01-16  |       800      |       =(530+350+670)-(400+350)
2020-01-17  |      1080      |       =(500+980+700+450)-(530+350+670)
```

---

I want to calculate the **total difference** of the `quantity` between two `timestamps`. 
Therefore, I tried to use the query from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69991131/calculate-the-difference-of-values-between-two-timestamps):

```
SELECT
t1.time_stamp AS time_stamp,
t1.quantity AS quantity,
COALESCE(t1.quantity-LAG(t1.quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.time_stamp ORDER BY t1.time_stamp), t1.quantity) AS difference
FROM 

  (SELECT
  l.time_stamp AS time_stamp, 
  SUM(l.quantity) AS quantity
  FROM logistics l
  GROUP BY 1
  ORDER BY 1) t1

GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

However, I am not able to get the expected result. 
What do I need to change to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `partition by` clause in the `lag` call of your query is redundant. The inner query is already grouped by the timestamp, so the outer query needn't (and shouldn't!) further partition the results.
With a `partition by` clause, each `lag` call is applied to just one timestamp (since they are already unique in the outer query), and you get the wrong result.

Remove it, and you should be fine:

```sql
SELECT
t1.time_stamp AS time_stamp,
t1.quantity AS quantity,
COALESCE(t1.quantity-LAG(t1.quantity) OVER (ORDER BY t1.time_stamp), t1.quantity) AS difference
FROM 

  (SELECT
  l.time_stamp AS time_stamp, 
  SUM(l.quantity) AS quantity
  FROM logistics l
  GROUP BY 1
  ORDER BY 1) t1

GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

**[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1cbcf099730196a4029e10bedf26e71c)**

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `PARTITION BY` in the `LAG` function.

If the "product" column was part of the result.
Then `PARTITION BY product` would make sense.
But since that's not the case, the `ORDER BY t1.time_stamp` is sufficient.

> ```
> SELECT
> t1.time_stamp AS time_stamp,
> t1.quantity AS quantity,
> COALESCE(t1.quantity-LAG(t1.quantity) OVER (ORDER BY t1.time_stamp), t1.quantity)
> AS difference
> FROM 
>
>   (SELECT
>   l.time_stamp AS time_stamp, 
>   SUM(l.quantity) AS quantity
>   FROM logistics l
>   GROUP BY 1
>   ORDER BY 1) t1
>
> GROUP BY 1,2
> ORDER BY 1,2;
> ```

> ```
> time_stamp | quantity | difference
> :--------- | -------: | ---------:
> 2020-01-14 |      400 |        400
> 2020-01-15 |      750 |        350
> 2020-01-16 |     1550 |        800
> 2020-01-17 |     2630 |       1080
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1839a302451191b727bf1fb0315b6cce)*

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```
select time_stamp
      ,s-COALESCE(LAG(t1.s) OVER  (ORDER BY t1.time_stamp),0)  as difference    
from 
 (select time_stamp,sum(quantity) as s 
       from logistics 
       group by time_stamp)t1
```

Output:

```
time_stamp  difference    
2020-01-14  400
2020-01-15  350
2020-01-16  800
2020-01-17  1080
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use a with clause, first calculate the sum, then its easier to calculate the lag:

```
with _sum as (
SELECT distinct
logistics.time_stamp AS time_stamp,
sum(quantity) over (PARTITION by time_stamp) as summe
from logistics
order by time_stamp
)
select 
time_stamp,
summe - coalesce(lag(summe) over (order by time_stamp),0)
from _sum
```